# Cannot draw corners round enough

Tags: java, android, kotlin, box2d, drawrect

The rounded Rectangles created with the same height and corner radius, but it seems that the x radius became longer and longer as the rectangle became wider.

The orners are not curves as I expected (blue stroke one).

Did I miss something on setting the canvas?

```
    canvas.save()
    canvas.translate(body.position.x * mDpm, body.position.y * mDpm)
    canvas.scale(bw * mDpm, bh * mDpm)
    canvas.rotate(getScreenRotate(body.angle))
    mPaint.style = Paint.Style.FILL
    mPaint.color = mColorFill
    val rect = RectF(-1f, -1f, 1f, 1f)
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, bh*2, bh*2, mPaint)
    canvas.restore()
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like the radius is scaled twice. First be `canvas.scale()`, and second by the way `bw` and `bh` are calculated. Since the rectangle has a fixed size before scaling, I would also expect that the radius has a fixed dimension. Please create a complete example so we can investigate if further.

Comment: It's a scale() method problem. I thought the same value of height gave the same corner. ;-( Thanks.